# Spectral norm of a symmetric strictly stochastic matrix on simple random walk

Tags: matrices, random-walk, spectral-radius, stochastic-matrices

I am considering the spectral norm of a transition matrix on simple random walk om $\mathbb{Z}^2$ as follows.

Let $S_n$ be a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$. Let $D$ be a connected subset of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $A$ be the matrix whose entries are the transition probability between the elements of $D$. The matrix $A$ has properties

1. A is a strictly doubly sub-stochastic matrix.
2. Every entry of A is $0$ or $\frac{1}{4}$.

Let $D$ be a ball with radius $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}^2$, that is $D=D_n= \{z \in \mathbb{Z}^2: |z|<n\}$. Here $|\cdot|$ represent for Euclidian norm in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

For instant with $n=2$ we have $D_2$ has 9 points, and the matrix $A$ as follows

$$A=A_2 =\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0
\end{matrix}\right).$$

Let $\lambda(D)$ be the spectral radius of A. It is the largest eigenvalue of $A$ since $A$ is symmetric.
Using Python, I can guess that if $n$ is large then $\lambda \approx 1$ moreover
$$1-\lambda \approx \frac{c}{n^2}.$$

I would like to prove that

*If $D_n$ is a ball with radius $n$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ then $$1-\lambda \approx \frac{c}{n^2}$$ as $n \to \infty$.*

May someone give me some hints or references to prove it?
Many thanks.

Comment: If it is doubly stochastic won't that imply that the vector $(1,1,1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ ? Maybe it is only "almost doubly-stochastic", by which I mean that all but $4n-4$ out of the $n^2$ rows will sum to $1$, and the rest will sum to either $3/4$ or $1/2$.  Can you give an example of the transition matrix $A$ corresponding to $D_n$ for moderate size $n$.

Comment: I have modified my question. I hope that it is clearer now. The matrix $A$ is a  strictly sub-stochastic matrix and its spectral radius is less than 1.